# How to disable any autoformatting and setup "block" identing for Razor pages in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor-pages

I need to write html + js code in .cshtml file and I don't want Visual Studio to format anything automatically, but it does:

1. VS aligns and formats spaces in js code line in .cshtml file each time when I past anything there
2. It adds one more tab when I opened an html tag like on "smart" identing but I just want to keep current tabs count (like on "block" identing)

I disabled:

- In Text editor settings:

  - Code Cleanup -> Run Code Cleanup profile on Save
  - Razor (ASP.NET Core)

    - Format On Type
    - Auto Insert Closing Tag
  - JavaScript/TypeScript -> Formatting -> General

    - Format completed line on Enter
    - Format completed statement on ;
    - Format opened block on {
    - Format completed block on }
    - Format on paste
  - ASP.NET Web Forms -> Miscellaneous -> Format on paste
  - C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> General

    - Automatically format on typing
    - Automatically format on return
    - Automatically format on paste